# Trying to overwrite default text in Dropzone react

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors

I inspected the code in the browser inspect. I know which specific property needs to be changed but I thing I need to point its key to a different class name.

I would like to change the overflow property to hidden and i would mike to remove the border and border-radius.

```
.dzu-dropzone {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 120px;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all .15s linear;
    border: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not already created, create **index.scss** file in your project repo.
there , add the code like this:

```
.dzu-dropzone {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will override the css while rendering. You can do the same for the border properties too.

Answer (score 0):

Youc can create two CSS files, a basic.css file with some minimal styling, and a more extensive dropzone.css. I added both and the style of my component was overriden.